# idiomatic way to declare protected method in Scala when allowing for composition?

Tags: scala, inheritance, composition, protected, idioms

I have an abstract class in package `foo` (in this particular case, a trait) that can be implemented by various subclasses, and I'd like to create an orthogonal subclass for use in a more specific package `bar` that adds package-specific info. It seems the best way is by composition (wrapping) rather than inheritance because otherwise I'd have to declare package-specific versions of every single one of the `foo`-package subclasses. But this leads to a problem with protected members which need to be forwarded:

```
package foo {
  trait Foo {
    protected def bar: Int
  }
}

package bar {
  import foo.Foo
  class Baz
  class WrapFoo(wrapped: Foo) extends Baz with Foo {
    protected def bar = wrapped.bar
  }
}
```

This leads to an error:

```
~/test/scala 14:54 152272% scalac testprotected.scala
testprotected.scala:11: error: method bar in trait Foo cannot be accessed in foo.Foo
 Access to protected method bar not permitted because
 prefix type foo.Foo does not conform to
 class WrapFoo in package bar where the access take place
    protected def bar = wrapped.bar
                                ^
one error found
```

Even though `WrapFoo` is a subclass of `Foo`, scala doesn't like the call `wrapped.bar`. I'm guessing this is because the object of type `WrapFoo` isn't a sub-object of `wrapped`.

The question is: What's the idiomatic way to declare the protections on `bar` other than simply making it public? The function `bar` is meant to be called by other functions in `Foo`, not publicly. Scala has an expressive protection system but I don't quite understand it. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Put both types in a common package, it can be anywhere in the package hierarchy and doesn't have to be an immediate parent.

Then you can use `protected[packagename]` or `private[packagename]` to selectively control access.

Comment: Is this the only way? In my case this has the effect of making the code accessible to the whole program. The package layout is already long established and rejiggering just for this would mess many other things up.